# Creating a thanksgiving brine for a 7-8 lb Turkey?

Tags: turkey, brining, thanksgiving

How much salt is one need for a typical brine for an average 7-8lb turkey?

Or is it more appropriate to ask what the ratios are of water to salt for a brine ?

I found a SA.SE question regarding brine and salt but it asked about salt content of the turkey: [How much salt does brining a turkey add?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/how-much-salt-does-brining-a-turkey-add)

Also, there was a link for information about brining on that thread but unfortunately, it's no longer available.

Comment: Where do you find a turkey as small as 8 lbs?  The brine ratio is the same for pretty much any turkey, regardless of size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/what-are-the-basics-and-options-of-brining-meat-for-example-chicken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alton Brown](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/good-eats-roast-turkey-recipe/index.html) uses 1 cup kosher salt and 1/2 cup sugar for 2 gallons of liquid (1 gallon ice water, 1 gallon vegetable stock).

You can reduce the amount of liquid to whatever you need to immerse the turkey in liquid. So for 1 gallon of liquid you would use 1/2 cup salt and 1/4 cup sugar.

The answers in [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1442/what-are-the-basics-and-options-of-brining-meat-for-example-chicken) recommend a brine that is 5-10% salt by weight (comparing salt to liquid).